# My Passport external drive, usb drive for Windows and for Mac

Tags: macos, usb, external-hard-drive

I'd like to have this My Password Essential external drive and my usb drive on both the Windows PC and the Mac.  I have had them only on the Windows PC and have backed up a lot of files on them.  I'd like to backup files on the Mac on these same drives and still be able to use them on the PC.  Is there something in particular that I must do for that?

Comment: Do you want to use some special `Western Digital My Passport Essential` backup software or is this a general question about how to use an external hard drive with both, Windows and Mac OS?

Comment: This is question about using My Passport essential on both.  I have already used it on the pc.  Can I use it on the Mac without reformatting.

Comment: Have you tried? Anymore it will probably just work. Years and years ago you might have needed to reformat the drive with a Mac-OS-specific FS, but I don't think that's the case anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use FAT-32 as the file system.  Both Windows and Mac can read and write that without additional software.

Note: Reformatting the file system will ERASE all the data on the drive.